# TensorFlow 1.x predict session outputs different values from the training session, given the same input

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a model based on CNNs, that works with timeseries and should classify the timeseries evaluated into 3 classes (0,1,2). During the training I am able to reach a very high accuracy. By giving a test dataset at the end of the training session I am able to obtain the following plot:

[image]

The code that I use to train and save the model is the following:

```
     sess = tf1.Session()
     saver = tf1.train.Saver()
            
    sess.run(tf1.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(0,epochs):
        step = 0
        l = 0.0
        val_acc = 0
        np.random.shuffle(TRAIN)
        for x,y in TRAIN:
            feed_dict = {self.net.input_tensor: x, self.label: y}
            _, compute_loss,comp_acc = sess.run([train_op, loss,accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict)

            l += compute_loss
            val_acc += comp_acc

            if step%100 == 0:
                #print(compute_loss,comp_acc)
                print('train step = %d,loss = %f,accuracy = %f'%(step, l/step, val_acc/step))
            step += 1
        val_acc = 0
        val_step = 0
        for x,y in TEST:
            feed_dict = {self.net.input_tensor: x, self.label: y}
            compute_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict)
            val_acc += compute_accuracy
            val_step += 1

        print("Validation set accuracy: %s" % str(val_acc/val_step))
        
    saver.save(sess, './model_v1/demo2/infer2')
    P = tf1.argmax(self.pred,1)
    evaluate(TX,TY,sess,self.net.input_tensor,P) # generates the plot, with input TX,TY
```

However, when I restore the session, the model will generate a completely different plot, given the same  input TX,TY:[image]

I am making sure that I do not run global_variables_initializer, when loading the session from the filesystem, as weights should come from restore, also that when I restore I start a new program, but still it is not working:

```
with tf1.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf1.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(r'./model_v1/demo2/infer2.meta')
  saver.restore(sess,r'./model_v1/demo2/infer2')
  graph = sess.graph
  inpt = graph.get_tensor_by_name('net_input:0') #name of the input placeholder
  output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('net_output:0') #name of the network output
  output = tf1.argmax(output, axis=1)    
  evaluate(TX,TY,sess, inpt,output)
```

The network is defined in the following manner:

```
def build_net_graph(self):
    self.input_tensor = tf1.placeholder(tf1.float32, [None, self.time_step, self.senor_data_num],name='net_input')

    #dense
    input_x = tf1.reshape(self.input_tensor, [-1, self.senor_data_num])
    
    weights_x = self._get_variable_weights([self.senor_data_num, self.num_units],"inputx_w")    
    biases_x = self._get_variable_biases([self.num_units],"inputx_b")
    x_mul = tf1.matmul(input_x, weights_x)
    x_output = tf1.reshape(tf1.add(x_mul, biases_x),[-1, self.time_step, self.num_units])
    
    #hidden layers        
    
    weights_outputs = self._get_variable_weights([avg_output.shape[1], self.class_num],"outputx_w")
    print("wo",weights_outputs.shape)
    biases_outputs = self._get_variable_biases([self.class_num],"outputx_b")
    
    m = tf1.matmul(hidden_layers_output, weights_outputs)
    a = tf1.add(m, biases_outputs)
    a = tf1.nn.softmax(a,name='net_output')
    return a
```

Can anyone give some help on what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the solution. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

It seems that the session.save is saving 2 versions of the weights in the same file, and by giving the original input and output names, 'net_input' and 'net_output' it restores the first version which is not the final.

I discovered this doing,
`print(self.pred.name)` before saving and it printed *net_output_1*, not *net_output*.
By running the following inference code I was able to obtain an identical evaluation plot as the one from the training:

```
with tf1.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf1.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(r'./model_v1/demo2/infer2.meta')
  saver.restore(sess,r'./model_v1/demo2/infer2')
  graph = sess.graph
  inpt = graph.get_tensor_by_name('net_input_1:0') #name of the input placeholder
  output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('net_output_1:0') #name of the network output
  output = tf1.argmax(output, axis=1)    
  evaluate(TX,TY,sess, inpt,output)
```